# how to clear input onchange validation message -ReactHooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I want to clear the input validation message after the validation is satisfied or the field is empty

I have 2 inputs where have to validate numbers onchange itself.I am using react hooks

code for onchange fields(can we format this 1 onchange)

```
 const onChangePhNum = React.useCallback(
(value: string) => {
  const FormattedValue1 =   onlynumberFormatter(value)
  props.setphoneNumber(FormattedValue1)
   /*clearMessage() */either any one of the message will be displayed
  if (FormattedValue1 === '' || FormattedValue1?.length < 15) {
    setShowValidationMessage(true)
    setMessage(
      person.path,
      "invalidPhoneNumber: length must be 10 digit",
    )
  }
},
[showValidationMessage, props.phoneNumber],
)

const onChangezipCode = React.useCallback(
(value: string) => {
  const FormattedValue2 = noSpecialCharacters(value)
  props.setzipcode(FormattedValue2)
   /*clearMessage() */either any one of the message will be displayed
  if (FormattedValue2 === '' || FormattedValue2.length < 4) {
    setShowValidationMessage(true)
    setMessage(
      person.path,
      "invalidzipcode:zipcode must be 4 digit",
    )
  }
},
[showValidationMessage, props.zipCode],
)
```

i have a clearMessage method also, but getting confused about when to call this

```
   const clearMessage = React.useCallback((message) => {
if (showValidationMessage) {
  clearMessages(
    person.path,
    message,
  )
  setShowValidationMessage(false)
}
}, [showValidationMessage])
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The result of validation must be clear understanding whether you have any validation issues or it is all clear. So it goes to state.
2. The validation message conditional rendering must be implemented.

Getting rid of all extra stuff, the basic case looks like:

```
const Component = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("")
  const [validationError, setValidationError] = useState("")
  
  function validate(string) {
    // some validation rules:
    if (string.length < 5) {
      return "Value must contain at least 5 symbols"
    }
    // basic return:
    return ""
  }
  
  function handleInputChange({target}) {
    setValidationError(validate(target.value))
    setInputValue(target.value)
  }
  
  return (
    <>
      <input value={inputValue} onChange={handleInputChange} />
      {validationError && <span>{validationError}</span>}
    </>
  )
}
```

Hope you will find it helpful.